# How to fix missing application icons on external HDD?

Tags: finder

I am trying to use external applications on my MacBook Air 2019 by making an alias and putting it in the launchpad.

However, the icons show up as generic on the external HDD and on the launchpad. Is there a way to restore the favicon in both locations?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. You can copy the icons from the original apps and paste them to the affected apps/aliases. Take a look at https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/create-custom-icons-files-folders-mac-mchlp2313/mac, section "Use an icon from another file or folder", for a detailed procedure.